# Create a numpy array according to another array along with indices array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array(eg., `a = np.array([ 8.,  2.])`), and another array which stores the indices I would like to get from the former array. (eg., `b = np.array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.])`.

What I would like to do is to create another array from these 2 arrays, in this case, it should be: `array([ 8.,  2.,  2.,  8.,  8.])`

of course, I can always use a for loop to achieve this goal:

```
for i in range(5):
    c[i] = a[b[i]]
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant method to create this array. Something like `c = a[b[0:5]]` (well, this apparently doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only integer arrays can be used for indexing, and you've created `b` as a `float64` array.  You can get what you're looking for if you explicitly convert to integer:

```
bi = np.array(b, dtype=int)
c = a[bi[0:5]]
```